# Initial conditions to falsify Rowland's conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, conjectures

Based on the [Rowland's paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL11/Rowland/rowland21.pdf) (A natural prime-generating recurrence), is there any theorem to show that for which initial condition $a(1) = k$ the conjecture can be falsified?

For example, for $k$ equals 532 or 801, the conjecture of "only 1 or prime for the recurrent formula $g(n) = a(n)-a(n-1) = \gcd(n, a(n-1))$" does not hold, mentioned in the same paper.

In sum, I am wondering if there is any theorem or conjecture to show some properties for (a subset of) such $k$s.

Comment: At https://oeis.org/A106108 there is the following comment: "
Not all starting values generate differences of all 1's or primes. The following a(1) generate composite differences: 532, 533, 534, 535, 698, 699, 706, 707, 708, 709, 712, 713, 714, 715, ... - Dmitry Kamenetsky, Jul 18 2015" but I saw nothing further on these values.